# How to redirect the returning data on to another view and put that data in chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I have a method which is taking date parameters and returning returning the list of Passengers in between those dates and displaying it on view. In view I have three buttons.

- **Export** (Exporting that list in excel)
- **Show Monthly Graph** (Displaying that record in the form of graph by using chart.js)
- **Show Date Wise Graph** ( Showing graph date wise)

**When I click Graph Button:**  It takes date by temp data and get the total number of passengers A/C to month in the form of Json . and than I am passing that data in graph using chart.js. And on the click button I hide the table which is returning the list , so my graph  will be more visible. This is all working so fine.

**What I am wishing ?**  I want to open the graph in another view , so it will be more visible. not in the same view..

View is here :

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("DateRecords", "PassengerInfo", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "3" }))
{
    <h2>All Records</h2>

        <div class="inner_page_about">
        </div>



        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="w3-row w3-border" style="width:100%">
            <div class="w3-container w3-half, col-md-4">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "PassengerInfo")'" value="Export Detail Data" />
            </div>
            <div class="w3-container w3-half, col-md-4">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="showGraph(false)" value="Month wise Graph" />
            </div>
            <div class="w3-container w3-half, col-md-4">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="showGraph(true)" value="Date wise Graph" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />


            <hr />
            <table id="1">




                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Seat Number</th>
                        <th>Sequence Number</th>
                        <th>Airline</th>
                        <th>FLight Number</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>CheckIn Time</th>
                        <th>Checkout Time</th>
                        <th>IsCheckout</th>
                        <th>Enter By</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Passengers)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>@item.Name</td>
                        <td>@item.SeatNo</td>
                        <td>@item.SequenceNo</td>
                        <td>@item.Airline</td>
                        <td>@item.FlightNo</td>
                        <td>@item.Date</td>
                        <td>@item.CheckinTime</td>
                        <td>@item.CheckoutTime</td>
                        <td>@item.IsCheckout</td>
                        <td>@item.EnterBy</td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
            <br />

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="myid2" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="myid" value="Next" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hfCurrentPageIndex" name="skip" />

            <canvas id="graph" width="30" height="40" style="display:none"></canvas>
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myid").click(function () {
        document.getElementById("hfCurrentPageIndex").value = @Model.skip +10;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myid2").click(function () {
        document.getElementById("hfCurrentPageIndex").value = @Model.skip -10;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    });
</script>
<script>
    function showGraph(dateWise) {
        $('#1').hide();
        $('#2').hide();
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetPassengerInfo")?startDate=@TempData["FromDate"].ToString()' + '&' + 'endDate=@TempData["ToDate"].ToString()&dateWise=' + dateWise;
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('graph'), {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: data.Labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            data: data.Counts,
                            label: "Total Passenger",
                            borderColor: "#e60053",
                            fill: true,
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Passenger Graph'
                        }
                    }
                })
                $('#graph').show();
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: you can have the '#graph' is partial view and open in another view. The graph data can be passed as model parameter to the graph view

Comment: I'm afraid this is confusing at best - please add more explanation to clarify what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean by saying _redirect the returning data on to another view_? "redirect" is incorrect for passing data. As you mentioned you  want to pass graph data to another view for showing it.

Comment: Ok so how can i do this ?